# Filter that will pass a message only if it contains one of words in list

Tags: ruby

I want to filter incoming info:

```
news = [
  'One day bla-bla-bla',
  'Long time ago bla-bla',
]
```

and pass messages that have one of the words that I specify:

```
mywords = ['ago', 'time', 'hero']
```

I tried:

```
messages = []
news.each do |item|
  mywords.each do |word|
    if item.include?(word)
      messages << item
      return
    end
  end
end
```

What is the Rails or Ruby way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mywords = %w(ago time hero)
news = [
  'One day bla-bla-bla',
  'Long time ago bla-bla'
]
news.select { |n| mywords.any? { |w| n =~ /\b#{w}\b/ } }
#⇒ ["Long time ago bla-bla"]
```

or even better:

```
news.select { |n| n =~ Regexp.union(mywords) }
#⇒ ["Long time ago bla-bla"]
```

Please note, that my answer is more robust than others two [currently posted] since it will not match the news “Superman calls back” against word “man”.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick:

```
news.select { |item| mywords.any? { |word| item.include? word } }
```

Comment: Lol. It wasn't so easy give the same answer.

Comment: Niceee... What are the chances?! @nobilik, same answers mean good answers :)

Comment: @Uzbekjon sorry, but mudasobwa show me my error also. but thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In one line

```
news.select { |item| my_words.any? { |word| item.include? word } }
```

Answer (score 0):

include does not check for words but for strings. Rather check if the news contains whole word, not part of it:

```
messages = []
allowed.each do |a|
  news.each do |n|
    messages << n if n =~ /\b#{a}\b/ 
  end
end
```

Comment: How this answer differs from mine, posted 5 mins ago (besides it is less ruby idiomatic)?

Comment: @mudasobwa despite what you might think it's not the race :)

Comment: Feel free to post duplicates, it’s just never appreciated here.

Comment: @mudasobwa hey, I entered the page and it was  EMPTY!!!!! 5 minutes is NOTHING. Do you understand that ?

Comment: and yeah, I also know some people who post 1 line, then edit to 2 lines, edit to 5 lines and so on just to be first. Is not good practice either but seems to be acceptable. So just calm down and live your day.

Comment: Duplicate answers are time-wasters. As I was reading your answer I thought, "Hey, isn't this the same as the answer I just read?" (If two answers that are the same and are posted within seconds of each other, I don't treat them as duplicates, and may upvote (or down vote) both, though the author of the later answer may voluntarily delete their answer.)